# Can I use Dreamweaver CS5 on Windows to manage local Linux files?

Tags: linux, dreamweaver

I'm running Dreamweaver CS5 on Windows 7. Currently, I set up sites in Dreamweaver so that the local site folder is a folder on a Windows server down the hall.

A new project will run on a Linux server (also just down the hall) and I'm being told by the Sys Admin to save my files (php, js, css, etc) on the Windows server and FTP them to the Linux server.

I realize Dreamweaver won't run on Linux. Can anyone tell me how to use Dreamweaver on Windows to read/write files from/to a local Linux server? If it's just a matter of typing in the path in Dreamweaver Site Setup, then what is the syntax (e.g., the analog to "\server\directory\subdirectory")?

Many thanks!
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to talk the sys admin into setting up samba access for you. Witha samba set up you could mount your samba share as a drive and use that as the site folder. Although I am not sure you would want all the extra files Dreamweaver brings to the table on your webserver.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! My apologies for the latency in following up.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Use dreamwaver's "Sites" feature to FTP the files over, if FTP was set-up on the Linux server.
2. Get the admins to set-up Samba on Linux, you would be able to use it just like a windows share as in \server\share ...